How to close a document without showing Word afterward?
I'm managing Word from my Delphi application to modify a single file without showing Word to the user.
Everything works well until the moment where I call the following code to close the document:
// FVBA is an OLE object extracted from a running instance of Word
FVBA.Application.Documents.Close;

After this, Word becomes visible and I have to hide it again.
I can set the Visible property to False after this, but my aim is to not show Word at all, even for a split second.  How can I do that?

Do you have more than one document in that instance?

no there is only one

If you're done using MS Word you might as well quit the application which also terminates out-of-process COM server (Word.exe). To do that along with keeping the changes you made to the document just call Application.Quit(wdSaveChanges);.

Application.Documents returns a documents collection that represents all the open documents.
In case to avoid the issue that Word becomes visible you could use the following loop even in case you only have one document
Dim d
For Each d In FVBA.Application.Documents
    d.Close False
Next d

or in case of one document FVBA.Application.Documents.item(1).close False

@Weewow Remember that if worked, mark the answer with the green mark :)
